# Image displays in samsung gs2 and smaller screen sizes but not in 10.1 inch tablet

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I seem to have a problem which I can't seem to figure out.  In my app i have a image 800x2200 (created in Photoshop). When I test the app on my samsung gs2 the image displays perfectly and can scroll up and down with no problems. And when testing on smaller screen sizes it works great, but it seems that when I test it on a 10.1 inch screen i just get a blank screen but can still scroll (as i can see the the scroll bar on the left, (as if there is a image, but it doesn't display) I have placed the image in all the drawable folders, but with no luck.  Has anyone got an idea of what the problem is or is it me doing something wrong?
Thanks

Sorry may code is:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 
    setContentView(R.layout.sample);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    final SlidingDrawer slider = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.slidingD1);
    Display d = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    d.getMetrics(dm);
    Log.d("DISPLAYINFO", "Classified density: " + dm.densityDpi + ", scaled density: " + dm.scaledDensity + ", actual densities: x: " + dm.xdpi + ", y: " + dm.ydpi);
    slider.animateOpen();

    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.img1);
    .....

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageV1)).setImageResource(0);
        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageV1)).setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
        slider.animateClose();
        } 
    });
    ......
}
}
```

and xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView 
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <RelativeLayout 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">    

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/imageV1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"/>

</RelativeLayout>
 </ScrollView>

<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/slidingD1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select Sample"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background_image">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/samp1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/samplethumb1"
                    android:text="Sample1"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="serif" />
```

Comment: No code? Seriously, how do you want us to help you?

Comment: The image seems to work when the dimensions are 800 x 2000 but it doesnt work when the image is 800 x 2100

Answer (score 1):

Check LogCat, does it state errors like

> OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture

anywhere? Changes are, your 10.1 tablet is significantly different from your smaller devices, in that it **runs on Ice Cream Sandwich**. This means hardware acceleration is turned *on* by default, which might maximize your image size to 2048px in both dimensions.

If this seems to be the problem, try [turning off hardware acceleration for your activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#controlling). Unfortunately, turning it off for a single view is currently not supported.

Comment: I have tried that but in the logcat it gives me a FATAL ERROR and then out of memory.